# UWP xaml ripple Effect (android effect) animation

Tags: c#, android, xaml, animation, uwp

I try to code in UWP app an Android Effect (ripple). So I create an EllipseGeometry Inside a grid (in my usercontrol) but when RadiusX and RadiusY of my ellipseGeometry play their animation, my EllipseGeometry growth out of my grid...
I have tried to bounds path with a visible area and clip it to the path, but no success.

Here my XAML code :

```
<UserControl
x:Class="UIComponents.POIButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UIComponents"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="100"
d:DesignWidth="650" Background="White">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Animation Ellipse-->
    <Grid x:Name="ellipseContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Path x:Name="path" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="circleGeometry" Center="0,0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="clickableRect" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  PointerPressed="clickableRect_PointerPressed"  Fill="Transparent" Tapped="clickableRect_Tapped"/>
</Grid>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="RipplePath">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusX" Storyboard.TargetName="circleGeometry">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="200"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusY" Storyboard.TargetName="circleGeometry">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="5"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:10" Value="200"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Here my Cs code :

```
private void clickableRect_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point touchPosition = e.GetPosition(ellipseContainer);
        //RectangleGeometry visibleArea = new RectangleGeometry();
        //visibleArea.Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 650, 100);
        //path.Clip = visibleArea;
        Storyboard animation = this.FindName("RipplePath") as Storyboard;
        animation.Begin();

    }
```

Here, the result :

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help :)

============== Try Justin XL's solution : result :

Thanks Justin for your Help, It seems the rectanglegeometry is animed too :

[image]

But nothing is over the grid.

the Xaml code is :

```
<UserControl
x:Class="UIComponents.POIButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UIComponents"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="100"
d:DesignWidth="650" Background="White">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,650,100" />
    </Grid.Clip> ...
```

and CS code is :

```
public POIButton()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
        visual.Clip = visual.Compositor.CreateInsetClip();
    }
```

================  XAML Result :

This XAML code not produce correct effect :

```
<UserControl
x:Class="UIComponents.POIButton"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:UIComponents"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Height="100"
Width="650" Background="White">
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,650,100" />
    </Grid.Clip>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Animation Ellipse-->
    <Grid x:Name="ellipseContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <Path x:Name="path" Fill="Red" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="circleGeometry" Center="0,0" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" />
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Grid>...
```

Result : 
[image]

But CS Code works fine (with comment the line RectangleGeometry  in XAML code) :

```
this.InitializeComponent();
        var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
        visual.Clip = visual.Compositor.CreateInsetClip();
```

Produce this :

[image]

Thanks @Justin XL for it help :)

Comment: Not an exact answer to your question, but you should check out the Color Bloom animation in this sample on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs). It might be of some use.

Comment: @JustinXL one more question related UI

Comment: BTW, the XAML approach should work too(I tried with your exact code n it worked perfectly), there must be something else in your code that caused the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to clip the control from going outside of its boundaries. This can be achieved by either using

```
<Grid x:Name="Root" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Background="Gray">
    <Grid.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,80" />
    </Grid.Clip>
```

in your XAML(`200` is the width and `80` is the height), or

```
public POIButton()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var visual = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this);
    visual.Clip = visual.Compositor.CreateInsetClip();
}
```

in code-behind with the new *Composition API*. Note with the XAML approach you need to manually update the width and height by bindings or code-behind if the size of your control changes, where with Composition, you don't.

Also, I have noticed you used a path animation which runs on the UI thread(e.g. `EnableDependentAnimation`). This can be replaced by a `Ellipse` with a `ScaleTransform` animation which is normally the recommended approach because of its much better performance.

---

### A "ripple" effect with `XamlLight`

Since you are developing for UWP, it's important to acknowledge what the platform can do, and the UWP way of achieving a similar effect, yet still honoring its own *Fluent Design System*.

I created the following `FluentButton` control as shown below with the help of a new [`XamlLight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.xamllight) class introduced in `15063`. You will notice that the light follows your mouse cursor, and it ripples upon click/tap.

[image]

The second part is done by a customized `XamlLight` which I called `RippleXamlLight`, and this is how it's implemented -

First, create a class that inherits from `XamlLight`.

```
public class RippleXamlLight : XamlLight
```

Then, in its `OnConnected` override method, create a `SpotLight` instance and a `Vector3` animation that will be used to animate the light's `Offset`. It will also take care of subscribing to pointer events such as `PointerPressed`.

```
protected override void OnConnected(UIElement newElement)
{
    _compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;

    var spotLight = CreateSpotLight();
    CompositionLight = spotLight;

    _lightRippleOffsetAnimation = CreateLightRippleOffsetAnimation();

    SubscribeToPointerEvents();

    AddTargetElement(GetId(), newElement);

    ...
    }
}
```

Finally, kick off the animation whenever the control is pressed. The `Offset` value is provided by the pointer position and a `_rippleOffsetZ` which is calculated based on the size of the control.

```
private void OnPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) =>
    StartLightRippleOffsetAnimation(e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Position.ToVector2());

private void StartLightRippleOffsetAnimation(Vector2 position)
{
    var startingPoisition = new Vector3(position, 0.0f);
    _lightRippleOffsetAnimation?.InsertKeyFrame(0.0f, startingPoisition);
    _lightRippleOffsetAnimation?.InsertKeyFrame(1.0f, new Vector3(position.X, position.Y, _rippleOffsetZ));

    CompositionLight?.StartAnimation("Offset", _lightRippleOffsetAnimation);
}
```

In case I didn't explain it clearly enough, here's the [full source](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/Continuity/blob/master/Continuity/Lights/RippleXamlLight.cs) for your reference. :)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried your solution in first part with clip on the grid with rectanglegeometry, but when the animation player it seems the rectangle is anim too ... I posted the result

Comment: You just need either the xaml or the cs approach, not both. Also, if you go with the xaml approach, you need to make sure your controls width and height are defined. Your xaml only defined the `d:DesignHeight` and `d:DesignWidth`. They need to be replaced by `Height` and `Width`.

Comment: I did what you recommend in Xaml but it seems not work. But CS Code works fine, thanks a lot :) . I will check if ellipseGeometry animation consume a lot of cpu/gpu performance now when with play an animation on RadiusX and RadiusY.